# selecting all row of max value of a column

Tags: mysql

I have this simple query.

```
SELECT 

    t3.C_COMDTY_SHORT_DESC
    ,t3.C_HS_CODE    
    ,t3.I_COMDTY_ID
FROM

    ADM_COMMODITY_MASTER t3 
WHERE
 t3.C_HS_CODE = '2203.00.00'
```

which return two rows as below.

[image]

Now i want to select the row of corresponding the column which has max *I_COMDTY_ID*.
so i write like this.

```
SELECT 

    t3.C_COMDTY_SHORT_DESC
    ,t3.C_HS_CODE    
    ,t3.I_COMDTY_ID,max(I_COMDTY_ID)
FROM

    ADM_COMMODITY_MASTER t3 
WHERE
 t3.C_HS_CODE = '2203.00.00'  group by t3.C_HS_CODE;
```

This is what is got.

[image]

Why column **C_COMDTY_SHORT_DESC** value is **BEER** ? I know how to get max row and other way around. But why it is not working ?

Comment: Please let me know if the table structure is required.

Answer (score 2):

Your query will get the max value of `I_COMDTY_ID` with ANY combination of the other fields from the rows that satisfies your `WHERE` condition.

A better way to do that:

```
SELECT 
    t3.C_COMDTY_SHORT_DESC,
    t3.C_HS_CODE,
    t3.I_COMDTY_ID,
    I_COMDTY_ID
FROM
    ADM_COMMODITY_MASTER t3 
WHERE
    t3.C_HS_CODE = '2203.00.00'  
ORDER BY 
    I_COMDTY_ID DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```